# Change fan curve on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, cpu, fan, overheating, temperature

I need to know how to change the fan curve on my laptop, specifically making the fan go up when the CPU reaches 80 C rather than 95 C because I don't want the CPU getting damaged by high temperatures. I can't seem to figure out how to do this with a Core i7 620M on a ThinkPad X201. Setting compute in sensors changes both the thresholds and the readings. How would I deal with this?

Comment: It depends on the laptop - what brand / model is it ?

Comment: It is a ThinkPad X201

Comment: Please ALWAYS [edit] your question when adding new information.

Comment: have you tried using the package 'fancontrol'?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install the required programs `sudo apt install lm-sensors fancontrol` then you can use `sensors-detect` to detect what sensors you have, follow the prompts and I normally just go with the defaults. Then after you have detected the sensors you can configure their curves with `pwmconfig` that will guide you through generating the `/etc/fancontrol` configuration file, after you're done you must start the `fancontrol` daemon by running `fancontrol` or rebooting. Once you started it make sure it started OK by doing `service fancontrol status`

Most of the time this works fine, but some boards don't let you control the fan or in the case of the Thinkpad T430 it uses ACPI to control the fans, if thats the case I always just write my own python script to do that, you normally can just write to the fan's file to change its speed in code.

You may need to add `options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1` to your `/etc/modprobe.d/options` file if you are using a thinkpad.
[Here is thinkwiki's article about it](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed#Automated_control_scripts)